# Memory leak when doing fire-and-forget of Task.Delay with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, memory-leaks, cancellation-token

In my application I need to schedule executing of some `Action`s with delay. It's like `setTimeout` in JavaScript. Also, when app execution ends I need to cancel all scheduled executions that have not been executed yet. So I have to call `Task.Delay` without await and pass `CancellationToken` into it. But if I do so, I face with memory leak: none of `CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode` will be disposed until I call `Cancel` and `Dispose` of `CancellationTokenSource` from which I take `CancellationToken`s to pass to `Task.Delay`.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Task.Delay(500, cts.Token).ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Scheduled action"));
}
await Task.Delay(1000);
Console.ReadLine();
```

After executing this example, it leave 1000 of `CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode`.
[image: with leak]

 
If I write `cts.Cancel()` after `await Task.Delay(1000);` leak does not appear
[image: without leak]

Why this leak happens? All `Task`s was completed, so there should not be references to `cts.Token`. Disposing passed `Task` to continuation action does not help.
Also, if I `await` Task that schedule execution of action, leak does not appear.

Comment: Unless you run a Task, it will not execute.  What you are doing it configuring a task to do something, but not actually running it.   You could capture the tasks as you create them and then call Tasks.WhenAll(taskList) which WILL schedule them.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add `GC.Collect()` before the `Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: Also what's the .NET runtime? .NET 6? .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: @Neil the `Task.Delay` creates a hot task. Awaiting the task is certainly not a requirement for that task getting scheduled. You might confusing it with the [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynclazy-1) type.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias not 100% convinced, but OK.   IMO you should never fire-and-forget a task, because you have no idea it's completed, or if an exception was thrown, and you don't know if it's been disposed.   It's OK to capture the task created and look later on, but I would reject any code that did what the OP's code does.  If your class creates an object, it's up to your class to dispose of it too.

Comment: @Neil about fire-and-forgetting tasks not being a good idea, I agree.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias , `GC.Collect()` before the `Console.ReadLine()` does not make any difference.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias , .NET 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was a bit surprised, but it looks like this is on purpose. When a registration is cancelled, `CancellationTokenSource` still keeps the instance of `CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode` in a free-list to reuse it for the next callback. This is an opiniated optimization, that can backfire in your scenario.

To illustrate this, try running your test twice in a row:

```
var tasks = new Task[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Delay(500, cts.Token).ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Scheduled action"));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Delay(500, cts.Token).ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Scheduled action"));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Console.ReadLine()
```

You will see that there are still 1000 instances of `CancellationTokenSource+CallbackNode`, despite registering 2000 callbacks in total. That's because the second iteration reused the nodes created during the first one.

Not much you can do about this, I believe this is by design. In any case, the amount of memory should be mostly negligible (at most `x` instances, where `x` is the number of simultaneously registered callbacks).

Comment: In case you're curious, the freelist was introduced in .NET Core 2.1.0: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/12819

Comment: This controversial optimization reminds me of a similar one in the Channels library: [Channels with CancellationTokenSource with timeout memory leak after dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573683/channels-with-cancellationtokensource-with-timeout-memory-leak-after-dispose). Depending on the angle from which you are looking it, it can be either a brilliant idea or a flaw. If you report this issue on GitHub, chances are that it will be dismissed as "by design".

Comment: *"Not much you can do about this"* why can't you just dispose `cts`?

Comment: @Charlieface Of course. I just meant "no way to reclaim the memory without disposing the cancellation token" (which might not be an option if for instance the token is tied to a long-running operation)