# Wait for function but with a timeout. How do I make my function async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, .net-6.0

I have the same requirement as the poster in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout). I want to **wait** for a function to return but also set a **timeout** value.

I want to use the part :

```
int timeout = 1000;
var task = SomeOperationAsync();
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}
```

but I have no idea how to make my function async.

When sending SMS via a modem I initiate the sending sequence and then waits for the modem to reply that it is ready for the message part.
All data that the modem sends to my software is categorized and then added to the appropriate *Channel*.

```
private async void WaitForReadyForSMSData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ModemData modemData;
        while (!_sendSMSChannel.Reader.TryRead(out modemData))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(ModemTimings.ChannelReadWait);
        }
        if (modemData.ModemMessageClasses.Exists(o => o == ModemDataClass.ReadyForSMSData))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part I want to make an async function out of but I am clueless.

Comment: What are `_sendSMSChannel` and `_sendSMSChannel.Reader` ? You can replace `Thread.Sleep` with `Task.Delay` to avoid blocking. Change the return type to `async Task` instead of `async void` so you can await that method

Comment: And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68998339/982149) doesn't work for you?

Comment: That is one of the channels I use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels

Comment: In that case why don't you use `ReadAsync` ?

Comment: I have looked at using ReadAsync but I don't know how to use it. I haven't worked with async before.

Comment: Then simply try it first. Haven't done something not yet is the norm when programming. When you still stumble over using ReadAsync then ask again with the code you tried.

Comment: As a side note the upcoming .NET 8 will produce a warning when a `Task.Delay` is used as an argument to `Task.WhenAny`, and that `Task.Delay` doesn't take a cancellation token: [Detect non-cancelable Task.Delay passed to Task.WhenAny](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33805).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Reader` is a ChannelReader, it's better to use [ReadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readasync?view=net-7.0) or [ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=net-7.0) instead of polling. The entire method can be replaced with :

```
var modemData =await _sendSMSChannel.Reader.ReadAsync();
```

`ReadAsync` can accept a CancellationToken to implement a timeout, although that may not be needed. Channels are typically used to create either work queues or pipelines. They're *meant* to be long lived.

```
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var modemData =await _sendSMSChannel.Reader.ReadAsync(cts.Token);
```

This will through a timeout exception if no message is received for 1 minute.

In an SMS sending service though, there's no real need for such a timeout, unless one intends to shut down the service after a while. In this case it's better to call [ChannelWriter.Complete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete?view=net-7.0) on the writer instead of nuking the reader.

**Using async foreach**

For normal operations, an asynchronous `foreach` can be used to read messages from the channel and send them, until the service shuts down *through the writer*. [ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=net-7.0) returns an `IAsyncEnumerable` that can be used for asynchronous looping

```
await foreach(var modemData in _sendSMSChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token))
{
    if (modemData.ModemMessageClasses.Exists(o => o == ModemDataClass.ReadyForSMSData))
    {
        await _smsSender.SendAsync(modemData);
    }
}
```

When the time comes to shut down the channel, calling `ChannelWriter.Complete` or `TryComplete` will cause the async loop to exit gracefully

```
public async Task StopAsync()
{
    _sendSMSChannel.Complete();
}
```

Assuming you use a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), the loop could go in [ExecuteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and `Complete` in [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

```
public override async ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    await foreach(var modemData in _sendSMSChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token))
    {
        if (modemData.ModemMessageClasses.Contains(ModemDataClass.ReadyForSMSData))
        {
            await _smsSender.SendAsync(modemData);
        }
    }
}

public override async StopAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    _sendSMSChannel.Complete();
    base.StopAsync(token);
}
```

**IAsyncEnumerable and LINQ**

[System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) provides LINQ operators on top of IAsyncEnumerable like `Where`. This can be used to filter messages for example :

```
public override async ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    var messageStream=_sendSMSChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token)
                         .Where(msg=>msg.ModemMessageClasses.Contains(ModemDataClass.ReadyForSMSData));

    await foreach(var modemData in messageStream)
    {
        await _smsSender.SendAsync(modemData);
    }
}
```

It's possible to extract the filtering clause to a separate method :

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<ModemData> this ReadyToSend(IAsyncEnumerable<ModemData> stream)
{
    return stream.Where(msg=>msg.ModemMessageClasses
                                .Contains(ModemDataClass.ReadyForSMSData));
}

...

public override async ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    var messageStream=_sendSMSChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token)
                         .ReadyToSend();

    await foreach(var modemData in messageStream)
    {
        await _smsSender.SendAsync(modemData);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a CancellationToken for automatic timeout. => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-ctor(system-timespan)

Comment: The problem is this, the read modemData may or may not be what I am after. If not I need to continue reading for subsequent modemData. But I need to timeout at some point in time. Ah OK. I have to check that CancellationToken.

Comment: @jeppe I added an example using `await foreach`. When and why do you want to time out though? The loop itself doesn't need to timeout. It's just waiting for some other thread to post messages to the channel. If you want to shut down the channel, call `Complete` on the writer

Comment: The channel name is misleading, it is just used when sending SMS and in this instance to know when the modem is ready for the SMS message data (PDU). Thanks for your input, it solved my problem. Haven't used channels before either. All new to me.

Comment: I want to timeout because in case is something wrong with the communication with the modem. I am testing with two different models and sometimes there is comms problems, usually software bug/handling on my part or modem being slow in responding.

Comment: Filtering also seems to be what I need.

Comment: You don't have to use a Channel for one-off events. That's what `TaskCompletionSource` is for. If you need to process a stream of messages that includes a `ready to send`, there are ways to do this using Rx.NET and maybe System.Linq.Async as well.

Comment: Excellent, then I can use a single channel. I have to check that out.

Comment: *"Channels [...] are meant to be long lived."* -- Citation? *"This will throw a timeout exception if no message is received for 1 minute."* -- Most likely an `OperationCanceledException`. *"ReadAsync(cts.Token)"* -- Beware of the [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573683/channels-with-cancellationtokensource-with-timeout-memory-leak-after-dispose) issue.

Comment: My channels lives as long as the application runs.