# Why a Channel needs a CancellationToken if it has Complete method?

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, system.threading.channels

I'm using `System.Threading.Channel`. The `Channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync` accepts a `CancellationToken`. But, there is also `Channel.Writer.TryComplete()` or `Channel.Writer.Complete()` methods. So, why would I use a cancellation token to stop waiting if I just can call `Complete` which will stop the waiting?

Answer (score 3):

The [`ChannelReader<T>.WaitToReadAsync(CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.waittoreadasync) allows a consumer of the channel to stop consuming the channel, either temporarily or permanently, by using the optional `cancellationToken` parameter. For example a consumer might have to do some periodic work every minute, in which case it could use a timer-based `CancellationTokenSource` in order to cancel the wait, do the periodic work, and then continue consuming¹.

The [`ChannelWriter<T>.Complete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete) prevents the producers of the channel from writing more messages, and when the channel is drained, it informs the consumers of the channel that no more messages are going to be available.

So these two APIs serve different purposes.

¹ <sub>Actually this pattern is currently problematic because of a [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573683/channels-with-cancellationtokensource-with-timeout-memory-leak-after-dispose) in the implementation of the built-in Channels.</sub>